# Why does Play build report error: package org.json does not exist with chargebee-1.0 in build.sbt?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to `import org.json` to my Play Framework project, but can't get rid of this error message:

> error: package org.json does not exist

Using Eclipse and I've added `org.json-chargebee-1.0.jar` to the Java Build Path, and the `build.sbt` file looks like this:

```
name := "sorlandsportalen"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      cache,
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26",
      "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.1.Final",
      "org.json"%"org.json"%"chargebee-1.0"     
      )

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

I'm using Play Framework version 2.2.1

Comment: Have you run `play update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `play eclipse` in the project's directory after having added the dependency `"org.json" % "org.json" % "chargebee-1.0"` to the project's build (definition) in `build.sbt`.

Refresh Eclipse and the issue should disappear (as `build.sbt` looks fine and I've tested it myself).